# setGlobalPrefix exclude endpoint nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

In my project all the APIs are prefixed with `/payments`. Now I want some of my APIs not to be prefixed with this.

In my `main.ts` to set global prefix I've used.

```
app.setGlobalPrefix('payments');
```

Some solution similar to middleware would be cleaner.

```
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) { }
  public configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    if (this.configService.get('REQUIRE_AUTH') !== 'FALSE') {
      consumer
        .apply(AuthMiddleware)
        .exclude({
          path: 'platform/healthcheck',
          method: RequestMethod.ALL,
        })
        // Like this
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of a global prefix you would have to set the prefix on the controller and then you can pick and choose what endpoints have it

Comment: [Did you read the docs?](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/global-prefix)

Answer (score 8):

You can pass the second parameter to setGlobalPrefix method which is an object, that would contain the property **exclude** and that type should be an array. Define the route names in that array. and that routes will be excluded from the prefix

```
app.setGlobalPrefix('v1', { exclude: ['healthcheck'] });
```

To see more about the setGlobalPrefix method check the below link

https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/global-prefix

Comment: Yes it worked, comment shared by Jay McDoniel

Comment: Thank you. 

and i was wasting my time, asking copilot chat XD